# Сохранения положения блока после выполнения анимации

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как реализовать следующие у меня есть блок который я смещаю на -405px по ховеру. Как сделать так чтобы после того как анимация выполнится блок остался смещённым на те же -405px

```
.seminar-info:hover {
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-name: seminar-info;
    }

@keyframes seminar-info {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left: -405px;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку анимация в вашем коде применяется только при наведении, то декларативно при помощи CSS вы не сможете оставить блок в конечном положении анимации, а значит вам понадобится JS. Ну а раз уж вы будете использовать JS, то лучше сразу перевести управление анимацией полностью туда. Можно, например записывать в дата-атрибут данные об анимации и стартовать её по `mouseover`

```js
document.querySelector('.block').onmouseover = function() {
  let x = +(this.dataset.movex);
  this.style.transform = 'translateX(' + x + 'px)';
}
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  transition: .5s transform;
}
```

```html
<div class=block data-movex=100></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так должно без JS работать

```css
.seminar-info {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: seminar-info;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.seminar-info:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes seminar-info {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }
    to {
        left: -405px;
    }
}
```